# Using recurrence relation to solve the given equation for $a_{n+2}= 7a_{n+1} -12a_n$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Find the general solution of the resurrence relation $a_{n+2}-7a_{n+1}+12a_n=0$.

so what I did is as follows:
I am using recurrence to solve this.

So the equation for the above will be $r^2-7r+12=0$. Solving the same we get roots as $r=4, 3$
so we can write $a_n = C_1 (4^n) + C_2(3^n)$

Is this okay or do I have to do some more steps after this?

Comment: You are done. If you want to find the values of $C_1$ and $C_2$ you need two initial conditions.

Comment: @Arnaldo Agreed but I have not been given any initial condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also express $C_1,\,C_2$ in terms of arbitrary initial conditions $a_0,\,a_1$ by determining $C_1,\,C_2$ from simultaneous equations $a_0=C_1+C_2,\,a_1=4C_1+3C_2$, viz.$$a_n=(a_1-3a_0)4^n+(4a_0-a_1)3^n.$$

Comment: I am sorry but which simultaneous equation. I did not understand.

Comment: @Dasha See edit.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are given some initial conditions, you are done.  If you have values at two points you can set up a pair of simultaneous equations to evaluate $C_1,C_2$

Comment: yup no initial condition is given. I got confused because $a_{n+2}= 7a_{n+1} -12a_n$. But I found for $a_n$

Comment: Come on! This is not an answer...

Comment: @Dasha:  $a_n$ is the general term of the series.  You also found $a_{n+2}=C_13^{n+2}+C_24^{n+2}$

Comment: @Raffaele:  I believe it answers exactly the question asked.  OP seemed concerned leaving the answer in that form with undetermined constants.

Comment: @RossMillikan Even I was also thinking this but was not sure if my approach is right. Thanks for the clarification